# Why does my Vue Router throw a Maximum call stack error?

Tags: vue.js, redirect, vue-router, electron-builder

I have a really simple routing practically looks like this I'm using this under electron

```
 import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Projects from "../views/Projects.vue";
import RegisterUser from "@/views/RegisterUser.vue";
//import { appHasOwner } from "@/services/";
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "projects",
    component: Projects,
    meta: {
      requiresUser: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    name: "register",
    component: RegisterUser
  },
  {
    path: "/settings",
    name: "settings",
    meta: {
      requiresUser: true
    },
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/Settings.vue")
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.requiresUser === true)) {
    //this will be for test case undefined
    let user;
    if (typeof user === "undefined") {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(user); //logs undefined but at the end no redirect
      next("/register");
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
});

export default router;
```

taking the example from the docs

```
// GOOD
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!isAuthenticated) next('/login')
  else next()
})
```

the application can boot only if there is a user attached in database either should redirect to the register component but the code above will end with `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. So how to check with `beforeEach` conditions end redirect to a given page?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Maximum call stack size exceeded` is usually due to infinite recursion, and that certainly seems to be the case here. In `router.beforeEach` you're calling `next` to go to the `/register` route, which goes back into this method, which calls `next`, and so on. I see you have a `requiresUser` in your `meta`, so you need to check that in `beforeEach`, like this:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // If the route's meta.requiresUser is true, make sure we have a user, otherwise redirect to /register
  if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.requiresUser === true)) {
    if (typeof user == "undefined") {
      next({ path: '/register' })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
  // Route doesn't require a user, so go ahead
  next()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I updated my codes to reflect your suggested

Comment: @fefe you also need to include `next()` at the end of the `beforeEach`. Right now you're only calling `next()` inside the first `if` block